# reading a json file in r lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: json, r

I tried to read a json file in r.

```
library(jsonlite)
m10.js <- readLines('metatest10.json')
m10.df <- fromJSON(m10.js)
```

I have the following error message.

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                          {'asin': '0110400550', 'related' 
                         (right here) ------^
```

I also tried 'stream_in' function.

```
stream_in(file("metatest10.json"))
```

Similar error message.

```
opening file input connection.  
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      {'asin': '0110400550', 'related'
                     (right here) ------^
closing file input connection.
```

How can I read the json file

[Here is the data](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8720C7F4B777B942!1293&authkey=!AElczzPx2k07yvQ&ithint=file%2Cjson)

Comment: Could be **copy & paste** issue. 

I had faced this kind of issue. 

example **“**, **"** are different.

Comment: can you tell us what `metatest10.json` looks like?